# Как получить значения столбца другой таблицы связанных отношением один ко многим в Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Имеются две модели: **users** и **zakaz**, связанные отношением "один ко многим":

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function zakaz()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Zakaz::class);
    }
```

В таблице zakaz хранится внешний ключ "users_id" ссылающаяся к таблице users к первичному ключу "id". В таблице users хранится столбец **name**, хранящий имя пользователя. В моделях пока не очень разбираюсь, поэтому хотел спросить: как получить значение **name** из таблицы **users** через таблицу **zakaz**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У заказа тоже должно быть указано отношение к таблице пользователья.

```
class Order {
    ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User:class);
    }

}
```

Теперь в коде вы у любого заказа можете получить пользователя

```
$userName = $order->user->name;
```